# Slugify issue in django template

Tags: python, django, slugify

I have a link in a django html template. I want to pass in a slugified string to the view for processing. I am getting an error and it is no slugifying the string. here is the code I have. Am I missing something or do i need to add something for slugify to work on the string...

```
<p><a href="{% url 'group_home' group.group.name|slugify %}">{{ group.group.name }}</a></p>
```

url:

`url(r'^(?P<groupname>[\w+]+)/$', views.group_home, name='group_home'),`

string example:

```
first group
```

here is the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /groups/
Reverse for 'group_home' with arguments '('first-group',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['groups/(?P<groupname>[\\w+]+)/$']
```

Another question I have is how do i unslugify a string once I am in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a hyphen on your regex. It will match the hyphens of your slugified string:

```
url(r'^(?P<groupname>[\w+-]+)/$', views.group_home, name='group_home'),
```

Why would you want to "unslugify"? Maybe you're looking for something like a [built-in class-based generic view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/). They allow you to retrieve an object based on the pk/slug specified in the url.

Comment: because the name in the database has spaces which is why when i filter the group object out i can filter it with spaces but you solution got it working